# If a topological space is covered by finitely many closed sets, then one of them has nonempty interior

Tags: general-topology

I got this question, which I have to prove by induction:

> Let $X$ be the topological space and $A_1, \dotsc, A_n$ closed subsets of $X$ with $\bigcup_{k=1}^n A_k = X$.
>   Then there exists some $i \in \{1,...,n\}$ such that $A_i^\circ \neq \emptyset$.

I really don't know how to prove that, not even how to start... Would be nice if you could give me some tips.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open set as a finite union of closed sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1325947/open-set-as-a-finite-union-of-closed-sets) (just focus on the answer)

Comment: $X$ should be nonempty at least.

Comment: By the way, just a linguistic (but I think important) point: don’t use the definite article “the” when talking about a newly introduced arbitrary toplogical space such as $X$. It should be “Let  $X$ be a topological space”.

Comment: Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the additional  assumption that $X\neq\emptyset$ here's your induction:

1. For $n=1$ this is clear because $A_1=X$
2. Assume it holds for some $n\geq 1$. Consider $n+1$ and $X=A_1\cup\cdots\cup A_{n+1}$. If $\text{int}(A_{n+1})\neq\emptyset$ then we are done so assume that $\text{int}(A_{n+1})=\emptyset$. Consider $$U=X\backslash(A_1\cup\cdots\cup A_n)$$ Note that it is open. Since $X=A_1\cup\cdots\cup A_{n+1}$ then this implies that $U\subseteq A_{n+1}$. So if $U$ is nonempty then it contradicts $\text{int}(A_{n+1})$ being empty. It follows that $U=\emptyset$ and so $$X=A_1\cup\cdots\cup A_{n}$$ We can now apply our induction hypothesis to conclude that $\text{int}(A_m)\neq\emptyset$ for some $m=1,\ldots, n$.

Comment: Thanks for proof! I have 1 question: What exactly is the induction hypothesis? Thats the only part i dont understand. I think that the induction hypothesis is that X does have a int(Am)≠∅ for n, thats why you showed that X is the same for n and n+1

Comment: @Mangafreak13 to be 100% clear: the induction hypothesis is: "for some $n\geq 1$ and any $n$ closed subsets $A_1,\ldots, A_n\subseteq X$ such that $A_1\cup\cdots\cup A_n=X$ there is $m$ such that $\text{int}(A_m)\neq\emptyset$". What we are proving is that under this hypothesis the same holds for $n+1$.

Comment: Thats what i meant, sorry that my english isnt good enough! Thanks i understand it now 100%

Answer (score 1):

Suppose all $A_n$ are closed with empty interior. Then $O_n=X\setminus A_n$ are open and dense (as $\overline{O_n}=X\setminus \operatorname{int}(A_n)= X$ by a general formula relating closures, interiors and complements).

But a finite intersection of open and dense sets is open and dense so cannot be empty while $\bigcap_{i=1}^n O_i = X\setminus \bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i= \emptyset$ by de Morgan..